# spring boot http3: Secure Connection Failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, http3

I have checkout [spring-boot-http-3-jetty](https://github.com/murphye/spring-boot-http-3-jetty) and run.
It's working as expected[http-3(h3) from 2nd request] furthermore, I want to test it with POST request with body so, I have added the following **thymeleaf** dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**To handle form request added Controller**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest;

@Controller
public class UploadController {
    @GetMapping("/upload")
    public String displayUploadForm(ServletRequest request, Model model) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("displayUploadForm:" + request.getProtocol());
        model.addAttribute("message", "hello from upload controller...");
        return "uploadForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/handleUpload")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
        return "uploadForm";
    }
}
```

**Added thymeleaf template**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div th:if="${message}">
        <h2 th:text="${message}"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/handleUpload">
            <table>
                <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

While hitting https://demo.local:9002/upload
It shows form like and getting response header

```
alt-svc h3=":9002"; ma=86400; persist=1
```

[image: upload form]

But after submitting form getting below error
[image: Secure Connection Failed]

I have import certificate in firefox.
Also with `RestController` GET request working with http-3 after initial request served with (http-2 & response header `alt-svc h3=":9002"; ma=86400; persist=1`

also notice sometime its working http-2 for consecutive request.

Note:

1. checking with latest firefox
2. java version 19 on windows os

Its there any other config need to check to work with http-3(h3)?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Have you tried sending the request via something like curL or Postman to see if there's any difference in behaviour? With browsers, CORS can be a problem for testing these things

Comment: same api you can check through postman and let us know what error are you getting

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine for me. I'm using latest Firefox on MacOS.

The repository that you took specifically talks about setting up the project on **MacOS** not on **Windows**.

**Note:** For Windows, **HTTP/3** is only supported on **Windows Server 2022** & **Windows 11**. It's not enabled by default.

**Important:** Follow this SO Answer - [How Do You Enable HTTP/3 on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706288/how-do-you-enable-http-3-on-iis) to enable **HTTP/3** on **Windows** and also to make your codebase work.

---

I'm providing the steps how I followed for MacOS.

- After I checkout the code, I executed the command - `brew install --HEAD -s curl/curl.rb` to install curl on my system.
- Executed the following the command to set the curl on the **PATH**:

  ```
  export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
  source ~/.zshrc
  which curl
  ```
- Then I have edited the host file via command `sudo nano /etc/hosts` (MacOS). In your case, you have to edit `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` for Windows to add the following ip and domain name.

  ```
  127.0.0.1       demo.local
  ```
- Now, I have added the code base you have provided. Project Structure.

[image]

- Running the code successfully. Screenshot:

[image]